# iOS write to a txt

Tags: ios, file-io

I want to write in a txt, but my code not working...

This is my code:

```
-(void)bestScore{
    if(cptScore > bestScore){
        bestScore = cptScore;
        highScore.text =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @" %.d", bestScore];
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bestScore" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *test = @"test";
        [test writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    }
}
```

I have already a file named bestScore.txt in my folder "Supporting Files"

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

EDIT : 
I can read my file "bestScore.txt" with this code :

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bestScore" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    highScore.text = textFromFile;
    bestScore = [textFromFile intValue];
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  Does it compile?  Does it crash?  Does it work, but instead of writing "test" it writes "ALL HAIL STEVE JOBS LORD OF THE IPHONES!"?

Comment: You can not write into a file inside your app bundle in iOS.  You should write your file into ~/Library/Preferences or somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
It's not working because nothing is writing in my txt, but my app is running without errors !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)bestScore{
    if(cptScore > bestScore){
        bestScore = cptScore;
        highScore.text =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @" %.d", bestScore];
        NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Preferences/bestScore.txt"];
        NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",bestStore];
        NSError *error;

       // save a new file with the new best score into ~/Library/Preferences/bestScore.txt
       if([test writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error])
       {
            // wrote to file successfully
            NSLog(@"succesfully wrote file to %@", filePath);
        } else {
            // there was a problem
            NSLog(@"could not write file to %@ because %@", filePath, [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

And to read the score back in, you can do:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Preferences/bestScore.txt"];
NSString *textFromFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if(textFromFile)
{
    highScore.text = textFromFile;
    bestScore = [textFromFile intValue];
} else {
    // if the file doesn't exist or if there's an error, initialize bestScore to zero
    bestScore = 0;
    highScore.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. And my console is empty :/
But if I remove the "!" in the if, I have this message : could not write file to /Users/ludovic/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/10B15625-FFAE-4A11-AF35-1946CE978426/Library/Preferences/bestScore.txt because (null)

Comment: I changed my code so you can see that it successfully saved.  "`writeToFile`" returns YES if the file successfully saved and NO if the file had a problem writing out.

Comment: What is the permission of the existing file named bestScore.txt? What happens if you delete that file, does the write operation then succeed?

Comment: Thanks but it's written "succesfully", and my file "bestScore.txt" is not changed :/

Comment: How I can see the permission please ? Sorry I'm a Newbie :(

Comment: edit your question to show how you are ***loading*** your bestScore.txt to get your "`bestScore`"

Comment: I don't load bestScore.txt. I can read the file without problem, but just when I want to write in, I have a problem. I am not sure to have understood your sentence, because I speak English medium

Comment: Tell me how you are reading your "bestScore.txt" file.  What are you typing into the Terminal or how are you looking at it? I'm confident that you ARE writing it out correctly.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code which allow to read my "bestScore.txt"

Comment: Just as I thought, you're reading from the "`bestScore.txt`" file you have within your application bundle (the very same one I told you that can't be modified or written over).  I'm editing my answer to show you how to read your bestScore back in.